# libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file - genymotion

Tags: fedora, libpng, genymotion

Every time I try to open my genymotion on my fedora machine I always get the error of

```
libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file
```

After searching on the internet I saw an answer about using the `yum provides */libpng12.so.0`
and the terminal prompts me with this:

```
libpng12-1.2.50-5.fc20.i686 : Old version of libpng, needed to run old binaries
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/libpng12.so.0



libpng12-1.2.50-5.fc20.x86_64 : Old version of libpng, needed to run old
                              : binaries
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libpng12.so.0



libpng12-1.2.50-6.fc20.i686 : Old version of libpng, needed to run old binaries
Repo        : updates
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/libpng12.so.0



libpng12-1.2.50-6.fc20.x86_64 : Old version of libpng, needed to run old
                              : binaries
Repo        : updates
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libpng12.so.0



libpng12-1.2.50-6.fc20.i686 : Old version of libpng, needed to run old binaries
Repo        : @updates
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/libpng12.so.0
```

and then I tried on using the 32 bit version of genymotion, I was able to use it but every time I try to use a device, my machine logs out and then genymotion crashes and when I checked the logs it says: `[Genymotion Player] [Warning] player: Fatal IO error: client killed`

right now I am using fedora 20 64bit.

Comment: Strange, I'm using Fedora 20 64bit as well, without issues. Although, a few months ago I had a very similar problem, but not sure how I resolved it.

Comment: after days of research, trial and errors and even reformating my machine again (still fedora 20 64 bit but I accidentally wiped out my Windows so no more dual booting for me :( ) I just do a installed an updated version of the libpng12.s0 and then genymotion starts normally without issues. :)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404213/install-libpng12-on-ubuntu-22-04?noredirect=1&lq=1  This fixed my problem for Ubuntu 22.04 for libpng12 missing

Answer (score 5):

You are missing libpng. Install libpng12 64-bit version with this command:

```
yum install libpng12.x86_64
```

Answer (score 1):

dnf install libpng12-1.2.50-9.fc23.i686